# Function doesn't return a value on all codepaths

Tags: vb.net

I got the warning: "Function doesn't return a value on all codepaths" for the following code:

```
Function Test() As Boolean

    Dim X As Integer = 5

    If X = 10 Then
        Return True
    End If

End Function
```

I do understand that I won't return a value in all code paths, since the If statement requires `X = 10` in order to access `Return`. But since the default value when creating a function is False, i expect that to be returned when the criteria isn't filled. So the function in reality does return a value on all code paths.

I assume that it is a bad practice to rely on the default value of the function, especially since the function is created to return a value in the first place. Can someone shed a light on the topic and help resolve my confusion?

I can remove the warning by changing the code to:

```
Function Test() As Boolean

    Dim X As Integer = 5

    If X = 10 Then
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If

End Function
```

Or

```
Function Test() As Boolean

    Dim X As Integer = 5

    Return (X = 10)

End Function
```

Comment: why "But since the default value when creating a function is False" the default values are for variables. I think you should go with the second approach then you're good to go and cover all the cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> since the default value when creating a function is False, i expect
>   that to be returned when the criteria isn't filled

No, that's a  wrong expectation. The reason why .NET doesn't do this is obvious: 
it's a way to prevent you from careless mistakes. Often you simply overlook that your code paths don't return a value, so if the method would assume that you want to return `False` then it would hide a bug.

So it forces you to provide the return value yourself.

In VB.NET you can also use `Exit Function`, then you are returning the default value for that type.

[MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/function-statement):

> If you use `Exit Function` without assigning a value to name, the
>   procedure returns the default value for the data type that's specified
>   in returntype. If returntype isn't specified, the procedure returns
>   Nothing, which is the default value for Object.

But in my opinion this is  bad practice and only there to be downwards compatible with VB6.

There is another way to leave a function without returning anything: if you throw an exception.

So the warning is a way to tell you that you should rethink your logic, it just reminds you that you might have forgotten a case. A final `Return something` at the end doesn't hurt you anyway:

```
Function Test() As Boolean
    Dim X As Integer = 5

    If X = 10 Then Return True

    Return False   
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation! I knew I was wrong and needed some guidance! Plus points for providing links and your own code sample! Have a great day Tim!